# storing data when app "ends"

Tags: android, database, object-lifetime

I have a small DB and read the required extract of data in a Singleton object stored statically like this in a class called MainDataManager:

```
public class MainDataManager {
    private static Context context;
    public static MainDataManager mainDataManager = null;

    public static MainDataManager getInstance(Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
        if (mainDataManager == null) {  
           ...get the data from DB
          ...put the data in static mainDataManager variable 
          } 
        return mainDataManager;
        }
```

Now in every class/activity of the app I can access the MainDataManager.mainDataManager data easily.

At some time I would like to save the data back to the database.

Currently I do this on each activity in

```
 @Override
    protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    saveState(); //saves the mainDataManager's data to the DB
    }
```

I would like to avoid this and think it is actually "save" enough if I update the database only when the user exits the app (whatever this means) - or even better when Android wants to destroy the MainDataManager object.

While I could put my `saveState()` call in activities in the `onDestroy()` method - I would prefer to only save the data to DB if the MainDataManager object gets destroyed. But there is no `onDestroy()` for a normal object.

What would be the best way to handle that?

ps the reason why I do not want to saveState() in each activity's `onDestroy()` is, because saving to database is quite slow even with very little data (esp. on older Android phones!) and this is just not the logic - just because any activity is beeing destroyed- to then update the DB.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be the best way to handle that?

The way you are presently handling it, albeit perhaps using an `AsyncTask` from `onPause()`, and only from activities where you are changing the data, and perhaps using some sort of `isDirty` flag to let you know if data does need to be persisted.

The *real* reason you do not want to wait until `onDestroy()` is that `onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to be called.

> I would prefer to only save the data to DB if the MainDataManager object gets destroyed.

That object will never be "destroyed" -- it will live until the process is terminated.

Comment: Thanks again :-). OK, then I leave it the way it is, however, as mentioned, updating even the smallest DB is quite slow, perhaps the "isDirty"-flag can reduce the time it needs to be updates. Doing in an AsyncTask is certainly a good way out - however, I am not sure, that the order in which the AsyncTasks get executed is actually always the correct one. Besides the minor issue about ensuring "synchronized" update methods.

Comment: @user387184: Access to a `SQLiteDatabase` is synchronized at the `SQLiteDatabase` level, so you should not have to worry about that particular problem. You can also more proactively store your data (e.g., based on a UI event) rather than waiting, where relevant.